# Replace string between characters using regx_replace

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one column , which contain values like - $test test12$ test14
I have to update the value the between $$.
like-$test done$ test14

I have tried to solve this by using :-

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE('$test test12$ test14','$(.*?)$','test done') from dual
> ```

But not working

**Given String** -$test test12$ test14
**Expected result** - $test done$ test14

Comment: What should happen if it has `$test test12$ test14$`

Answer (score 3):

The character `$` is a rexeg *metacharacter*, which has a special meaning (it means the end of the input or current line).  It you want to target literal `$`, then it needs to be escaped:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('$test test12$ test14', '\$(.*?)\$','$test done$')
FROM dual;
```

The above outputs:

```
$test done$ test14
```